# Ошибка при отправке ботом сообщения vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

При отправке сообщения ботом пользователю, крашится с ошибкой: `vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [901] Can't send messages for users without permission`, у бота имеются все нужные разрешение в настройках, так же у пользователя нет запрета на сообщения.

Код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="Тут ваш токен")

vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "Айди сообщества (Не кастомное) пример: 94124211")

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.obj.text != "":
            if event.from_user:
                vk.messages.send(
                        user_id=event.obj.from_id,
                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                        message=event.obj.text)
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить, в чём была проблема. Интересно ведь :) Был ли я прав в своём ответе?

Comment: @nomnoms12, проблема не решена, считай что своеобразный метод закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Мне кажется, это плохой вариант. Найти ответ так станет намного сложнее. Если проблема не решена, то вопрос открыт. Зачем же его закрывать?

Comment: Думаю многие уже найдут ответ в вашем ответе, так что...

Comment: Кстати если подать неверный user_id, например event.obj.id вместо event.obj.from_id, будет такая же ошибка, потому что этот айдишник попадет в случайного пользователя, который не разрешал отправлять сообщения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

901 - Пользователь запретил отправку сообщений от имени сообщества. Это значит, либо пользователь запретил получать сообщения от группы, либо ещё не писал в неё. Если, пользователь ВКонтакте не написал сообщение в группу, значит он и не может получать их, так как это скорее всего как анти-спам.

Answer (score 2):

Сам встретился с этой ошибкой, проблема оказалась в том, что мой бот пытался ответить на своё же сообщение, т.е. getFromId и getText на проблемном сообщении показал ответ сервера и минусовой id, вместо ожидаемого сообщения пользователя

Как сообщение бота попадает в пачку сообщений от вк пока разбираюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Переписка с сообществом может быть инициирована **только самим пользователем**. Написать от имени группы людям, которые не переписывались с ним, не получится. Однако, когда переписка инициирована, сообщество сможет отправлять сообщения без ограничений по времени или количеству. Это будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока пользователь не запретит сообществу себе писать.

Пользователь может **инициировать переписку**:

- отправив сообществу сообщение со страницы сообщества;
- с помощью кнопки «Разрешить сообщения» на странице сообщества;
- отправив сообществу сообщение с помощью виджета [«Сообщения
  сообщества»](https://vk.com/blog/community-widget), размещённого на сайте сообщества;
- разрешив отправлять ему личные сообщения с помощью виджета
  [«Разрешить писать
  сообществу»](https://vk.com/dev/AllowMessagesFromCommunity) или
  [метода API VK в стороннем
  приложении](https://vk.com/dev/messages.allowMessagesFromGroup)
  (отправлять сообщение для этого не требуется).

<sup>*Источник: [Сообщения сообщества](https://vk.com/page-59800369_51260649).*</sup>

Comment: Я в вопросе написал, что разрешения есть на сообщения.
Значит, пользователь уже писал сообществу.

Comment: @Slavatar ВК имеет другое мнение на этот счёт. Код ошибки `901` означает _"Пользователь запретил отправку сообщений от имени сообщества"_. Это цитата из [официальной документации](https://vk.com/dev/manuals) по методу [`messages.send`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send).

Comment: @Slavatar Из того, что пользователь уже писал сообществу, не следует наличие у Вас разрешения на отправку сообщений ему в данный момент. Ничто не мешает пользователю запретить себе писать. По ссылке из моего ответа Вы можете найти как минимум 3 способа сделать это.

Comment: под пользователем - я имел введу себя. Я не запрещал сообщения. И эта ошибка очень странная, т.к сообщение отправится и только после она даст о себе знать

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в ID пользователя.
Можно использовать:
event.user_id